# Automatic update of firefox

Tags: upgrade, firefox

Is there a way to update Firefox automatically -- including snaps and upgrades?  No matter how much snap refreshing. upgrading, and updating I do, I (and many others) keep getting those damned messages. I'm looking for something that will stop those messages altogether.

Comment: There are several ways to stop "*those damned messages*," but they tend to be rather intrusive (install the deb instead) or to leave your system insecure (disable notifications). It is unclear if you are seeking that kind of solution, or if you are simply having trouble with the `snap refresh` command.

Comment: Firefox like almost all snaps is updated simply by running the Updates tool, provided Firefox ISN'T running at the same time. However, unlike what happens with software from the repositories (.deb), the snap updates won't be listed. Instead `snap refresh` runs automatically right after the other updates. Or you can open Ubuntu software and update from there. Again, you mustn't have Firefox running.

Comment: I just did 'killall firefox' followed by "snap refresh".  I'll report back if and when I get more of those messages.

Comment: I am curious what these "damned messages" are bout. You may want to clarify and be more specific in your question.

Comment: The persistent message was "Pending update of Firefox snap".

Comment: one day later - so far, so good.

Comment: A few days later, the problem is back.

Answer (score 0):

The messages you are seeing pop up constantly show up in the top panel (Notification List) & popup in Ubuntu.  They look like:

[image: snap message]

You should be able to turn those off in Settings...Notifications...

Choose the snapd user session agent.

[image: settings...notifications]

You can turn off the Notification Popups and they will still show up in the Notification List at the top of your screen but you will only see them when you click that area.